# How to add a continuous color scale to a go.scatter plot in dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash app with a scatterplot. I am using go.scatter and have set marker_color to be a continuous variable, but I want to be able to set the colorscale to cividis and to have a colorbar legend. How can I do this?
I tried using color_continuous_scale and got the error: ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Scatter: 'color'. In my app, I am uploading data, but for the sake of reproducibility, I have used the Iris dataset in this example.

```
external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
    dcc.Upload(
        id="upload-data",
        children=html.Div(["Drag and Drop or ", html.A("Select Files")]),
        multiple=True,
    ), dcc.Graph(id="Mygraph"),
        html.Div(id="output-data-upload"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('Mygraph', 'figure'), [
Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
Input('upload-data', 'filename'),

])
def update_graph(contents, filename):
    x = []
    y = []
    color=[]

    df_two=px.data.iris()
    x=df_two['sepal_length']
    y=df_two['sepal_width']
    color=df_two['sepal_length']
        
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Scatter(
                mode="markers", 
                x=x, 
                y=y,
                marker_color=color,
             # This line doesn't work:   color_continuous_scale='cividis',
                showlegend=True
                    )
               
            ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            width=500,
            height=500,
        ))
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',  
        dtick = 10
    ),
        yaxis=dict(
        tickmode= 'linear',
        dtick=10
        )
)
    return fig
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use with the colornames, colorbar and legend with ´go.Scatter´ for yours Marker you must enter the properties directly in the Markers of your scatter plot.

Some examples [here](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/).

Here is an example of your modified code :

```
@app.callback(Output('Mygraph', 'figure'), [
Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
Input('upload-data', 'filename'),

])
def update_graph(contents, filename):
    x = []
    y = []
    color=[]

    df_two=px.data.iris()
    x=df_two['sepal_length']
    y=df_two['sepal_width']
    color=df_two['sepal_length']
    
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[
            go.Scatter(
                mode="markers", 
                x=x, 
                y=y,
                marker_color=color,
                marker=dict(
                  colorscale="Cividis",  
                  colorbar=dict(title='Colorbar')),
                showlegend=False,
                
                    )
               
            ],
        layout=go.Layout(
            width=500,
            height=500,
        ))
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'linear',  
        dtick = 10
    ),
        yaxis=dict(
        tickmode= 'linear',
        dtick=10
        )
)
    return fig
```

I hope it could help you.